# Wordpress Settings API withing Singleton Class

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-4-on-theme-options--wp-24902) but instead of just spawning code into the functions.php file, I'm trying to build a personal framework, so I can use this in other projects.

Anyway, I wasn't able to date to make the settings fields appear in the Theme settings page. What am I doing wrong?

**Tee Config Class** - base class for theme options subpage

http://codepad.org/7nfIuenF

**Tee Settings Class** - `setup_configs_page` starts TeeConfig class and builds theme subpage

http://codepad.org/daCsnW2u

**Theme Inits** - Creates the instance of Tee Settings Class

http://codepad.org/9FaSm52x

**Functions.php**

http://codepad.org/rTxEMKQM

Comment: Where's the class instantiation? E.g., `new tee_configs();`.

Comment: updated. In another class "tee_settings"

Comment: I've turned on debug and I got this warning `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options' not found or invalid function name  `

Comment: set sandbox_initialize_theme_options() as a public function.

Comment: No luck with that. Also, I think that functions are public by default unless you specify them to be private/protected

Comment: its a visibility issue, try array( self:: or &$this, functionname) in your other callbacks.

Comment: Scratch that. I had a line in functions.php for testing which was causing that message. However, the problem persists. I can't see settings fields with this code.

Comment: tbh i cant see where you actually call the function sandbox_initialize_theme_options(), or maybe just my eyes at this time of night..

Comment: I call it inside another class. Which gets included with `require_once` in functions.php

Comment: João, the code you're showing is not enough to do a simple copy/paste and test/debug... Can you do a [**minimal example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @brasofilo Reformulated whole question. Hope it gets more clear now. Thanks for the help

Comment: All of these callbacks need to be array($this, "your_call_back_function")

Comment: Thats why you get these "Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'sandbox_initialize_theme_options' not found or invalid"

Comment: Keep your WP_DEBUG set to true when developing.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the fact that the admin_init hook is called before the init hook.

If you move the add_action('admin_init'...) into tee-settings, the solution can be found.
In addition, all of your callbacks for the elements require the array( $this, 'cb' ); structure.

**Here is the updated tee-settings.php**
http://codepad.org/re6Kkade

*note lines 26 and 48-50*

**and tee-configs.php**
http://codepad.org/EZr1kHDg

*note lines 21-23, 56, 64, 75, and 87.*